# Windows Forms: ctrl button prevents ListView from scrolling with mouse wheel

Tags: c#, .net

I want to scroll ListView with mouse wheel while Ctrl button is pressed. But apparently pressing Ctrl changes scroll behavior: it stops scrolling, possibly tries to apply some zooming logic, I don't know. And I can't find out how to override that.
Please any help or suggestions?

Comment: What kind of project?...WinForms maybe?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Sorry, yes, Windows forms

Answer (score 2):

The solution to get mouse wheel scrolling working while Ctrl key is held down is to listen for the `WndProc` event and specifically detecting `MOUSEWHEEL` trigger, minimum simple working example:

ListBox with `WndProc` override

```
class CtrlListBoxScroll : ListBox
{
    private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x114;
    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
    private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x20A;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
        {
            var scrollDirection = NativeMethods.GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(m.WParam);
            // scrolling down
            if (this.TopIndex < this.Items.Count && scrollDirection < 0)
            {
                this.TopIndex += 1;
            }
            // scrolling up
            if (this.TopIndex > 0 && scrollDirection > 0)
            {
                this.TopIndex -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NativeMethods to read the wParam and detect scroll direction

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    internal static ushort HIWORD(IntPtr dwValue)
    {
        return (ushort)((((long)dwValue) >> 0x10) & 0xffff);
    }

    internal static ushort HIWORD(uint dwValue)
    {
        return (ushort)(dwValue >> 0x10);
    }

    internal static int GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(IntPtr wParam)
    {
        return (short)HIWORD(wParam);
    }

    internal static int GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(uint wParam)
    {
        return (short)HIWORD(wParam);
    }
}
```

Then finally testing it

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctrlListBoxScroll = new CtrlListBoxScroll();
    ctrlListBoxScroll.Items.AddRange
    (
        new object[]
        {
            "hello", "scroll", "bar", "pressing", "ctrl", "to scroll",
            "this", "list", "box", "check", "ctrl", "key", "is", "held"
        }
    );
    this.Controls.Add(ctrlListBoxScroll);
}
```

Comment: Obscure fact: the argument passed to OnMouseWheel() is actually a HandledMouseEventArgs.  Which lets you cast the e argument in a method override and set its Handled property to true.  Cuts out a lot of the gritty code.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,13550

Comment: A ListBox is not the same thing as a ListView, where you can have different views that show things in a GRID (small icon, large icon, etc).  So the code will be a little more complicated in figuring out how to set [TopItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.topitem?view=netframework-4.5.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ListView.TopItem);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) based on the number of things being displayed in each row.